# Hector_quadrotor catkin_make fails compiling

Tags: hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am attempting to  install hector_quadrotor_tutorial from source on ubuntu 14.10, ROS indigo. And I am experiencing the following problems:
1st I had to install hardware_interface package which was missing. After successful installation of the package still can't compile. Here is the output:
Thanks in advance.

```
[ 98%] Building CXX object ros_control/controller_manager_tests/CMakeFiles/controller_manager_tests.dir/src/my_dummy_controller.cpp.o
```

In file included from /home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/src/pose_estimation_node.cpp:29:0:
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/include/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/pose_estimation_node.h:41:76: error: ‘StatePtr’ does not name a type
QuadrotorPoseEstimationNode(const SystemPtr& system = SystemPtr(), const StatePtr& state = StatePtr());
^
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/include/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/pose_estimation_node.h:41:103: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘state’ with no type [-fpermissive]
QuadrotorPoseEstimationNode(const SystemPtr& system = SystemPtr(), const StatePtr& state = StatePtr());
^
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/include/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/pose_estimation_node.h:41:103: error: ‘StatePtr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/src/pose_estimation_node.cpp:34:89: error: ‘StatePtr’ does not name a type
QuadrotorPoseEstimationNode::QuadrotorPoseEstimationNode(const SystemPtr& system, const StatePtr& state)
^
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/src/pose_estimation_node.cpp:34:99: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘state’ with no type [-fpermissive]
QuadrotorPoseEstimationNode::QuadrotorPoseEstimationNode(const SystemPtr& system, const StatePtr& state)
^
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/src/pose_estimation_node.cpp: In constructor ‘hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation::QuadrotorPoseEstimationNode::QuadrotorPoseEstimationNode(const SystemPtr&, const int&)’:
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/src/pose_estimation_node.cpp:35:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘hector_pose_estimation::PoseEstimationNode::PoseEstimationNode(const SystemPtr&, const int&)’
: PoseEstimationNode(system, state)
^
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/src/pose_estimation_node.cpp:35:37: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/include/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/pose_estimation_node.h:32:0,
from /home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/src/pose_estimation_node.cpp:29:
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation/include/hector_pose_estimation/pose_estimation_node.h:61:3: note: hector_pose_estimation::PoseEstimationNode::PoseEstimationNode(const SystemPtr&)
PoseEstimationNode(const SystemPtr& system = SystemPtr());
^
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation/include/hector_pose_estimation/pose_estimation_node.h:61:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation/include/hector_pose_estimation/pose_estimation_node.h:59:7: note: hector_pose_estimation::PoseEstimationNode::PoseEstimationNode(hector_pose_estimation::PoseEstimationNode&)
class PoseEstimationNode {
^
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation/include/hector_pose_estimation/pose_estimation_node.h:59:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/src/pose_estimation_node.cpp: In member function ‘void hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation::QuadrotorPoseEstimationNode::baroCallback(const AltimeterConstPtr&)’:
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/src/pose_estimation_node.cpp:54:7: error: ‘sensor_pose_publisher_’ was not declared in this scope
if (sensor_pose_publisher_) {
^
/home/marcello/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/src/pose_estimation_node.cpp:56:5: error: ‘sensor_pose_’ was not declared in this scope
sensor_pose_.pose.position.z = baro->getModel()->getAltitude(Baro::Update(altimeter->pressure, altimeter->qnh)) - baro->getElevation();
^

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198478/hector_quadrotor-catkin_make-fails-compiling/) by [scar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20962/scar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did a major update of the hector_pose_estimation packages during the last one or two weeks, which I [merged into the catkin branch](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_localization/commit/c876f76f53982c86b2fd1f07b060ec7384149f3f) a few minutes ago. hector_quadrotor already had some patches that I accidentally pushed and that require the new version. The state of the repositories was therefore inconsistent for a few days. I am sorry.

If you want, please try again with the updated versions now. You have to build both repos, hector_quadrotor and hector_localization, from source.

It also should be noted here that with the default values of the launch file arguments the simulated quadrotor directly uses ground truth information from Gazebo for control and for the published tf transforms. hector_pose_estimation is only started if the quadrotor is spawned with the `use_ground_truth_for_control:=true` roslaunch argument.

For the hardware_interface issue: Please make sure that all dependencies are installed before building, e.g. using [rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep) or [rosinstall_generator](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator). hardware_interface is an indirect dependency of hector_quadrotor_gazebo (and hector_quadrotor_demo):

```
$ rospack depends-why --target=hardware_interface hector_quadrotor_gazebo
Dependency chains from hector_quadrotor_gazebo to hardware_interface:
* hector_quadrotor_gazebo -> hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo -> gazebo_ros_control -> controller_manager -> controller_interface -> hardware_interface 
* hector_quadrotor_gazebo -> hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo -> gazebo_ros_control -> controller_manager -> hardware_interface 
* hector_quadrotor_gazebo -> hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo -> hector_quadrotor_controller -> hardware_interface 
* hector_quadrotor_gazebo -> hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo -> hector_quadrotor_controller -> controller_interface -> hardware_interface
```

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2014-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0